# Difference between manual/console upload to S3 vs. programatic upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We recently encountered some differences between csv files uploaded manually to S3 via Console vs. programmatically upload csv file. We noticed that the manually uploaded file (from console) had added double quotes, meanwhile the programmatically upload file does not. For example:

**Manual Upload (Console):**
"ID"|"TYPE"|"DATE"
"123456     "|"B  "|"2021-12-06  "

**Programmatic Upload:**
ID|TYPE|DATE
123456     |B  |2021-12-06

The intention is that we'd programmatically upload files in production so we'd likely only encounter this difference in development account. But, I'd like to understand why this is the case?

Comment: I would not expect uploading via the S3 console to modify the file contents and a quick test confirms that it does not. I uploaded your pipe-separated file (the one without quotes) using the S3 console, then downloaded it from S3 using both the S3 console and the awscli. In both cases, the downloaded file was identical to the original (without quotes).  I suspect there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something in your environment as uploading a file via the AWS Management Console ***does not modify*** the file content. I copied your content and uploaded via the Console. When i downloaded and opened the file, it was the same as shown here:

[image]

Comment: You're correct. I double checked and it's actually an error in the export process to csv.